# Is there a more efficient way to watermark and join videos in bulk through ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I have this batch file using ffmpeg to add a logo to my videos and then add an intro but it's taking anywhere from 10 hours to a day depending on how many I have to watermark, is there a more efficient way to achieve this? The videos sometimes have different resolutions so I can't remove the conversion to the 1280*720 size.

```
for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%I" -i white.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0];[1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 23 -codec:a copy "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"

for %%I in ("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\work\*.mp4") do ffmpeg -y -i %%I -c copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -s 1280*720 %%I.ts && ffmpeg -y -i "concat:out1.ts|%%I.ts|out1.ts" -c:v libx264 -strict experimental -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -ar 48000 -r 20 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Complete-videos\%%~nI.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: A question about improving an already working code should be asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In your first command, why the first scale filter? In your 2nd command, the size option has no effect as you're copying the streams. You could do all of this in one command, and skip one video encoding step. Your final encoding step could use a fast preset. Doesn't make much difference in quality.

Comment: Won't the first command results be overwritten by the second?

Comment: Yes, I want it to overwrite itself with the updated version, the first scale filter is to scale the watermark to the video and then place it in the bottom right corner.

Comment: @Mulvya You said that I could do this in one command, I agree but, how would I do this? I tried slapping an && in there so it'd watermark the video and immediately append the intro to said video but it didn't work properly.

Comment: The first scale filter is `[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0]` - which is applied to the main video. Why?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't exactly know how to scale the watermark so that was a solution I found here for it, I believed that section set the values for the iw and ih variables to then be used by the scale2ref part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single command:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i white.png -i out1.ts -filter_complex
  "[1][0]scale2ref=iw/6:ih/18[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=W-w-3:H-h-1,scale=hd720[vid];
   [2][2:a][vid][0:a][2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -r 20 -preset fast -ar 48000 out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
:: make a tempdir
:maketemp
SET "tempdir=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempdir%\" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (MD "%tempdir%")

:: read each filename from source and process

for %%I in ("%sourcedir%\*.txt") DO (
  TITLE Processing %%I
  START "%%I" q43060025s "%%I"
  CALL :wait 10
)
CALL :wait 1
RD "%tempdir%"

GOTO :EOF

:: monitor number of files in temp directory and return if fewer than %1
:wait
:: wait 1 second
timeout /t 1 >NUL
FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b /a-d "%tempdir%\*" 2^>nul ^| find /c /v "" ') DO IF %%c geq %1 GOTO wait
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. I used some dummy `.txt` files for testing.

The time requirement is probably being caused because you are serially processing the files. The solution is to process the files in parallel, using the power of the multiple cores in modern PCs.

The idea here is to make a temporary directory to contain control files, then process each file using a sub-procedure batch (`q43060025s.bat`)

The sub-procedure inherits the calling procedure's environment, so `tempdir` will be established.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: do some operation on the filename passed as %1
title processing %~1
ECHO %time%>"%tempdir%\%~n1"
:: 4 to 21-second delay
SET /a delay=%RANDOM% %% 18 + 4
timeout /t %delay% >NUL
DEL "%tempdir%\%~n1"
CLS
exit
```

So - the subprocedure here is a dummy for demonstration. It uses `tempdir` and creates a file in that directory with the name of the file-to-be-processed containing *something* - I just used the time.

My sub-procedure simply then delays for 4 to 21 seconds, simulating some process with a variable processing time.

It then deletes the file it created and terminates.

Meanwhile, the main procedure is monitoring the number of files in the temporary directory, which is the number of sub-processes running. Simply count the files and if the count is greater than or equal to the parameter passed, then wait for 1 second and try again.

As the sub-procedure finishes its job, the count is reduced and the `:wait` routine will exit. The next file is selected, despatched to the sub-process and we wait again.

When the last file has been sent, we continue to wait until the count of sub-processes is zero (ie. less than 1) when we can delete the temporary directory.

So - all you need to do is construct your processing in place of the delay routine in `q43060025s` using the filename passed as `%1` and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Excellent answer! It didn't occur to me to implement it in parallel, I'll see if I can adapt my code to work in such a way.