# Batch processing multiple files at the same time

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have this batch command

```
@echo off
FOR %%i in (C:\input\*.*) DO (
echo processing %%i
if not exist "C:\output\%%i" process.exe "%%i" -out "C:\output\%%i"
)
echo ---- finished ----
pause
```

Here my tool `process.exe` processes in a loop all files within a directory - if a result doesn't already exist.

Now my CPU is fast enough to run this `process.exe` on 2 or 3 files at the same time which would make the processing of the files much faster.

**Question:** How do I have to change the command to make my batch file processing 2-3 files at the same time?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Start` command usage information `/?`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43064770/2128947 may assist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/676667/73070 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following starts processes up to a max count of `%bunch%`. Whenever one of them finishes, another one will be started.

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set bunch=3

for %%a in (C:\input\*) do (
  call :loop 
  echo processing: %%a
  start "MyCommand" cmd /c timeout 60
  REM if not exist "C:\output\%%i" start "MyCommand" cmd /c process.exe "%%i" -out "C:\output\%%i"

)
call :loop
goto :eof

:loop  REM waits for available slot
echo on
for /f %%x in ('tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq MyCommand"  ^| find /c "cmd.exe"') do set x=%%x
if %x% geq %bunch% goto :loop
echo off
goto :eof
```

I don't have your `process.exe`, so I have to guess. but the `REM`ed line should work for you. (the `timeout` command is just to show the princip)