# How to stop a task, kill process(s), and restart task through CMD or powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a task that runs a program every 10 minutes to scan a directory, convert .doc to .pdf and relocate them to a different directory.

Unfortunately, the program cannot handle large amounts of `winword.exe` processes so it often stops in progress. When this happens, the .doc files continue to build and I have to manually move files so it's a bit time-consuming.

I wrote an exe (`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k task kill /IM winword.exe /F`) and dropped on the desktop. I use this to kill all `winword.exe` processes so it clears the system after I stop the Task, and restart the task again afterwards.

Essentially, just trying to use one function to END a task, run a script to kill `winword.exe` processes, and RUN a task once the processes are killed but not sure what function would be best to do this.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Isn't the obvious solution to [limit the number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49551035/2152082) of winword processes?

Comment: Instead of a task every 10 minutes, maybe you could consider a single script with an infinite loop that just runs all the time.

Answer (score 0):

While the best solution here would be to limit how many `winword` processes run at once as part of the program as @Stephan mentioned, if you want to stop a scheduled task, kill all `winword` processes, and start the task again, you can do so as follows in a Powershell script:

```
Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Name of Scheduled Task"
Get-Process winword | Stop-Process -Force
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Name of Scheduled Task"
```

Documentation on [`Stop-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/stop-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps), [`Start-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/start-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps), [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6), and [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-6) can be found at the preceeding links.