# Run model executable in parallel with status report

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, cmd, simulink

I have a Simulink model from which I compiled an executable.  Then, I'm using a batch file (*.bat) with 20 million lines of 'start /B model_name.exe' with a input file specified for each simulation as shown below:

```
start /B name_mdl.exe -u input_1.txt -o output_1.mat >>report_1.txt
start /B name_mdl.exe -u input_2.txt -o output_2.mat >>report_2.txt
start /B name_mdl.exe -u input_3.txt -o output_3.mat >>report_3.txt
```

and it goes on.  "-u" and "-o" might be specific options to a customized tool with which the executable was built.  I don't know if those are universal options.  input_N.txt has a syntax: variable name = its value.  report_N.txt has just bunch of information such as simulation run time, dates, times, etc.

Is there a way to have the batch file display (in Matlab command window) which cases are being run or how many have been performed?  It would look like the below, maybe:

```
start /B name_mdl.exe -u input_1.txt -o output_1.mat >>report_1.txt
printf('%d case completed',num_case);
start /B name_mdl.exe -u input_2.txt -o output_2.mat >>report_2.txt
printf('%d case completed',num_case);
```

It could just be a main batch file that launches the batch file above, but also has lines of code to have the operating system periodically count *.mat files in the current directory and spit out the count in the command window.

Comment: Please post at least part of your existing .bat file so we have something to go off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for /l` loop. The `in` clause defines`(<start>,<increment>,<end>)`

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,20000000) do (
  start /B name_mdl.exe -u input_%%i.txt -o output_%%i.mat >>report_%%i.txt
  echo started nr %%i 
)
```

(I can imagine, your PC gets over its limits with that. You should consider to [limit the count of parallel processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49551035/2152082))

To get the count of `*.mat` files, you can count them with:

```
for /f %%c in ('dir /b /a-d *.mat ^|find /c /v ""') do set count=%%c
echo There are %count% .mat files.
```

Comment: thank you much.  Do I use another *.bat file with both blocks in?  Teach me little bit more on the implementation, please.

Comment: I can't because I don't know MatLab or your environment or your needs. (You know at least two of those three)

Comment: I'll experiment.  Thank you much.